# Instagram API: JSON.parse() cannot read property of undefined Node Js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, instagram-api

I am using the Instagram API to search for a specific tag and then display the first result's image. Here I am using the `JSON.parse()` function parse the JSON that comes back from making a http get request to `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag}/media/recent?access_token={access token}`. Here is what the request is returning me (- everything that doesn't matter). Note: I blanked out parts of the URL's, assume that they are correct.

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "images":{  
            "low_resolution":{  
               "url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/--------_--------6248_1327489376_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=--------",
               "width":320,
               "height":320
            },
            "thumbnail":{  
               "url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/--------_--------6248_1327489376_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=--------",
               "width":150,
               "height":150
            },
            "standard_resolution":{  
               "url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/--------_--------6248_1327489376_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=--------",
               "width":640,
               "height":640
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is the code I am using to make the request and parse the JSON:

```
request.get("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/" + tag + "/media/recent?access_token=" + accessToken, function(error, response, body)
                                 {
                                 console.log(JSON.parse(body).data.images.standard_resolution.url)
                                 });
                     });
```

When ever I run this code it gives me this error:

```
/Users/pjtnt11/Documents/NodeJs/Instagram/index.js:52
                                 console.log(JSON.parse(body).data.images.standard_resolution.url)
                                                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined
    at Request._callback (/Users/pjtnt11/Documents/NodeJs/Instagram/index.js:52:67)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/pjtnt11/Documents/NodeJs/Instagram/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/pjtnt11/Documents/NodeJs/Instagram/node_modules/request/request.js:1044:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/pjtnt11/Documents/NodeJs/Instagram/node_modules/request/request.js:965:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
```

I thought that maybe it could have been because `console.log()` was running before `JSON.parse()` but `JSON.parse` blocks the code from running anything else. I also check if it had a callback or a promise that I could use but I didn't see anything.

Now I have no idea what is going on. Does anyone know what could be causing this error and how I could fix it?

EDIT:
Okay, so I found out that `data` is a data array, so I need to change my  code to be `data[0]` the problem now is I get the following error when I run the code:

```
/Users/pjtnt11/Documents/NodeJs/Instagram/index.js:52
                                 console.log(JSON.parse(body).data[0].images.standard_resolution.url)
                                                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Request._callback (/Users/pjtnt11/Documents/NodeJs/Instagram/index.js:52:67)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/pjtnt11/Documents/NodeJs/Instagram/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/pjtnt11/Documents/NodeJs/Instagram/node_modules/request/request.js:1044:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/pjtnt11/Documents/NodeJs/Instagram/node_modules/request/request.js:965:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
```

Comment: since you're making the URLs unusable, perhaps you could put an example of the JSON being returned in your question

Comment: @Tibrogargan Its right under the first paragraph of text already

Comment: sorry, missed that. data is an array.  you probably want data[0].images

Comment: Do a `console.log(JSON.parse(body))` on what you get back.  The error message is telling you that you don't have a `.data` property after parsing like you think you do.  In other words, when it reads the `.data` property, it is `undefined` so when you then try to read `data.images`, that's an error.

Comment: @jfriend00 But how is it undefined? If you look at the JSON that I am parsing its clear that the data property is there.

Comment: as @Tibrogargan said. data is an array of objects so for getting images you need `JSON.parse(body).data[0].images`

Comment: @pjtnt11 It's pretty clear that what you're getting back in `body` does not match the JSON you have posted.  This is why it's important to post an [mcve].  No-one can reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: @eltonkamami - Look, it will take you a couple minutes max to just put a `console.log(body)` and `console.log(body.data)` into your code and see what is actually there.  OBVIOUSLY, it isn't what you expect it to be.  This is basic debugging which you should learn how to do on your own before coming here.  Once you do that, the problem will either be obvious to you or you can add those results to your question and then maybe we can help you more directly.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an Array, so you need to access the first element...

`JSON.parse(body).data[0].images`

see following working snippet...

```js
var someObject = '{ \
   "data":[ \
      { \
         "images":{ \
            "low_resolution":{ \
               "url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/--------_--------6248_1327489376_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=--------", \
               "width":320, \
               "height":320 \
            }, \
            "thumbnail":{ \
               "url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/--------_--------6248_1327489376_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=--------", \
               "width":150, \
               "height":150 \
            }, \
            "standard_resolution":{ \
               "url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/--------_--------6248_1327489376_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=--------", \
               "width":640, \
               "height":640 \
            } \
         } \
      } \
   ] \
}';



console.log(JSON.parse(someObject).data[0].images.low_resolution.url);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I made an edit to my post explaining.

Comment: most likely `body` doesn't have what you think, maybe try `response` ? but given the JSON posted, the above works...